# The dimension of a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, quaternions

Let $D$ be an irreducible  $\mathbb{R}$-algebra in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ that it implies  $D$ has  independent vectors as $\{A_{1},...,A_{r^{2}}\}$. Let $D$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$ (quaternions) that it impiles the dimension of $D$ is $4$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Then we want to show $r=2$. To this end, it is enough to show that the dimension of $D$ is $r^{2}$. 
How?

Comment: Well, what does "$D$ has $r^{2}$ number of independent vectors" mean?  Is that the exact phrasing you were given?

Comment: Yes...Ok...I edit this...

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287911/an-irreducible-real-algebra), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287133/an-irreducible-mathbbr-algebra)?

Answer (score 0):

You are presumably meant to assume that $\{A_{1},...,A_{r^{2}}\}$ is a basis for $D$, not just a set of linearly independent elements.  If all you know is that they are linearly independent, then all you can conclude is that $r\leq 2$.

Comment: OK. but $D$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Now, What do we do?

Comment: @user448189 You can't conclude $r=2$, because $r$ could be $1$. Any singleton subset (other than $\{0\}$) of $D$ would be linearly independent. If you change "linearly independent" to "basis," then that implies $r^2$ is the dimension of $D$, which is $4$, and $r^2=4$ implies $r=2$.

Comment: I edit now... Let $D$ be  irreducible. This implies that there are linearly independent elements in  $D$ to number of $r^{2}$ as a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra in $M_{r}(\mathbb{C})$.